# creating a new Angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web

im trying to create a new Angular project, but im getting this error. i have installed an updated node also.

```
- Installing packages...
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-adapter failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.23.35:443
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...\r\n-----END PGP SIGN'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AUGUST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-13T07_26_40_996Z-debug.log
├ù Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ng new`? What is your `ng --version`, are you sure you are up-to-date with Angular CLI as well? (Also, you should use at least Node LTS version (12.18 at the moment), check with `node -v`).

Also, try cleaning your cache:
`npm cache clean --force`
then try the command again.

Comment: Ok thanks. Although sometimes it shows a different error. Still about depreciated stuff and all that. I will out the solution thanks a lot.